# C# XmlWriter does not turn ' to &apos;

Tags: c#, xml, escaping, xmlwriter

I have read several related posts but still could not figure out if `XmlWriter` can turn `'` to `&apos;` without using any libraries.

So far I know that the 5 characters to be escaped (`&`, `<`, `>`, `'` and `"`) are handled automatically by XML. But I want the apostrophe (`'`) to be turned into `&apos`; and with the `XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString` this does not occur and if I use `string.Replace` I get `&amp;apos;`.

This is what I get after conversion:

```
"Test Cue 1  &gt; '"
```

I want the result to be:

```
"Test Cue 1  &gt; &apos;"
```

Comment: Unclear. What is 'conversion'? Can you show your code? When you say 'result', result of what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XmlWriter` escapes what needs to be escaped to make valid XML (and not more). A string delimited by double-quotes does not need enclosed single-quotes to be escaped, and vice versa. Should you manually replace `'` with `&apos;` it won't understand what you're trying to do and will naturally escape the `&`.

Could you explain your use case?